# Is it a JSON string? Get array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I import data from WordPress. It is a WebDirectory 2.0 that saves the data as a "strange" string in a database.

Example:

```
s:95:"a:2:{s:3:"url";s:39:"http://www.google.com/";s:4:"text";s:13:"Website";}";
```

I have tried *json_decode()* and *unserialize()*. Both do not work. They return the string as it is. I can see, this is an array with two values, but how this can be parsed in PHP? In what format this string can be?

Comment: It looks like a string that has been serialized twice, so it must be unserialized twice.

Comment: No, that's not JSON

Answer (score 1):

If you have this:

```
echo serialize(serialize(['url'=>'http://www.google.com/','text'=>'Website']));
```

The output will be

```
s:71:"a:2:{s:3:"url";s:22:"http://www.google.com/";s:4:"text";s:7:"Website";}";
```

But what you have is

```
s:95:"a:2:{s:3:"url";s:39:"http://www.google.com/";s:4:"text";s:13:"Website";}";
```

Which is different. See, s:95 != s:71, among other elements.

Or this is not a real data or by some reason it's generating extra chars, and causing the problem. I would check how the encoding from both PHP and database to see if all matches.

Comment: I think OP changed the string to remove sensitive data.